# how to add sounds while uiscrollview is scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, audio

```
    -(void)layoutScrollImages
{
UIImageView *view = nil;
NSArray *subviews = [scrollView1 subviews];
CGFloat curXLoc = 0;
for (view in subviews)
{if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view.tag > 0)
{
CGRect frame = view.frame;
frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);
view.frame = frame;
curXLoc += (kScrollObjWidth);
}
}
    [scrollView1 setContentSize:CGSizeMake((kNumImages * kScrollObjWidth), [scrollView1 bounds].size.height)];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [scrollView1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[scrollView1 setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
scrollView1.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;

scrollView1.clipsToBounds = YES;
scrollView1.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollView1.pagingEnabled = YES;
NSUInteger i;
for (i = 1; i <= kNumImages; i++)
{
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"snap%d.jpg", i];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
rect.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;
rect.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;
    imageView.frame = rect;imageView.tag = i;
[scrollView1 addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
[self layoutScrollImages];
}
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: format your code so it is possible to read it

Comment: Checkout `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` in `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

Answer (score 2):

add `UIScrollViewDelegate` to your interface and then do your task in

```
scrollViewWillBeginDragging or `scrollViewDidEndDragging`

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView // called on start of dragging (may require some time and or distance to move)
{
    //add your code here

}
```

now this method will be called whenever you drag the scrollview

Comment: how to use this 'scrollViewWillBeginDragging' give me a brief code pls.

Comment: in this 'scrollViewWillBeginDragging' which code,i want to add AVAudioplyer or someother code..

Comment: yes avaudioplayer. which audio you want to play