# How to add sound while UIScrollview is scrolling in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, touch-event, audio

This is my code for adding sound while UIScrollview is scrolling in iPhone SDK. In this code, how to add the sound while using touch-events in scrolling?
Please give me your idea and suggestion or sample.

```
const CGFloat kScrollObjHeight  = 151.0;
const CGFloat kScrollObjWidth   =320.0;    
const NSUInteger kNumImages  = 5;

- (void)layoutScrollImages
{
  UIImageView *view = nil;
  NSArray *subviews = [scrollView1 subviews];
  CGFloat curXLoc = 0;
  for (view in subviews)
    {
      if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] &amp;&amp; view.tag &gt; 0)
       {
        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);
        view.frame = frame;
        curXLoc += (kScrollObjWidth);
       }
    }
   [scrollView1 setContentSize:CGSizeMake((kNumImages * kScrollObjWidth), [scrollView1 bounds].size.height)];
 }

- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   [scrollView1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
   [scrollView1 setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
   scrollView1.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
   scrollView1.clipsToBounds = YES; 
   scrollView1.scrollEnabled = YES;
   scrollView1.pagingEnabled = YES;
   NSUInteger i;
   for (i = 1; i &lt;= kNumImages; i++)
   {
     NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@&quot;snap%d.jpg&quot;, i];
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
     UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
     CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
     rect.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;
     rect.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;
     imageView.frame = rect;
     imageView.tag = i;
     [scrollView1 addSubview:imageView];
     [imageView release];
     [self layoutScrollImages];
   }
   [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: **I tried so many tutorials, but i didn't get any solution for this problem.. so please help me..**

Comment: please format your code for better readability

Comment: @SangeethRajan You've asked this question almost four times already. You've gotten many answers from your other posts about this topic, so either edit your previous posts if you don't understand the answers you've been given or continue to research on your own, but don't continue to ask this question over and over again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add sounds while uiscrollview is scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830635/how-to-add-sounds-while-uiscrollview-is-scrolling)

Answer (score 1):

add `UIScrollViewDelegate` to your interface and then play sound while the scrolling is in task in `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` state and stop scrolling while in  `scrollViewDidEndDragging` state.

You can use [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/) to play sound on iOS devices

**UPDATE:**

Tells the delegate when the scroll view is about to start scrolling the content.

`- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

Also, Tells the delegate when dragging ended in the scroll view.

`- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate`

Implement these in your code & put in your custom behavior

Comment: Hi Srikar, 

Could you please send me any sample code or reference link?

Comment: i can't understood..pls give me a brief explanation code by inserting AVAudioplayer.

Answer (score 0):

you mast use  UIScrollViewDelegate method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
   //play sound here 
}
```